# Recover deleted components in proteus

Tags: pcb, components, proteus

I'm new in proteus. Unfortunately I delete components in `PCB layout` mode without attention. Is there any way to recover them? I can see all of components in `Schematic Capture` mode and my simulation works well.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a component in the PCB layout, it should automatically go back into the component section which is represented on the left hand menu by the little op-amp symbol.

Go to this tab, and you should be able to select them and add them to the PCB layout.